# Como especificar 2 formatos a TimeSpan.TryParse?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

Existe la posibilidad de poder especificar dos formatos al TimeSpan.TryParse?

Tengo un campo de texto, en cual debo formatear el texto ingresado por el usuario al tipo Time, en este campo de texto debo permitir que el usuario ingrese los datos en el formato 24 Horas, y si es válido al campo de texto perder el focus, debe mostrar el valor en formato 12 horas.

Es decir:

```
Formato de Edición: HH:mm
Formáto a Mostrar: hh:mm tt
```

Esta función valida correctamente si ingreso una hora en formato 24 horas. Pero si coloco la hora en formato 12 horas no la reconoce como válida.

```
public bool IsValidTimeFormat(string entrada)
{
      if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(entrada)) return false;

      return TimeSpan.TryParse(entrada, out var salida);
}

private void text1_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
     if (IsValidTimeFormat(text1.Text))
     {
         text1.Text = Convert.ToDateTime(text1.Text).ToString("hh:mm tt");
     }
     else
     {
         MessageBox.Show("La hora digitada no tiene un formato correcto.\nPor favor Verifique.", "ERROR FORMATO", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
         text1.Focus();
         return;
     }
 }
```

Como podría espeficiar ambos formatos?

`[ws][-]{ d | [d.]hh:mm[:ss[.ff]] }[ws]`

```
return TimeSpan.TryParse(entrada, IFormatProvider formatProvider, out var salida);
```

Nota: Cabe destacar que NO puedo utilizar un `DateTimePicker` para este propósito.

Comment: No, no puedes. Pero puedes probar uno y si no es valido, probar el otro. Por cierto..si es una fecha, porque usas `TimeSpan`?

Comment: @Pikoh ok comprendo, podrias indicarme como hacerlo con el código, por favor.

Comment: La entrada es una hora? hh:mm o HH:mm?

Comment: @Pikoh por lo general, la entrada debería ser HH:mm, pero algunos usuarios aveces también ingresan hh:mm tt

Comment: Puedes probar con `TimeSpan.TryParseExact()`, doc [aquí](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.timespan.tryparseexact?view=netframework-4.6). O crear una expresión regular que te permita detectar los valores relativamente independientemente del formato de entrada, entre un grupo de formatos que especifiques.

Comment: @V.Lorz, como podría usar esta expresión regular `new Regex(@"^(?:(?:0?[0-9]|1[0-2]):[0-5][0-9] [ap]m|(?:[01][0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9])$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);` según ví aquí esta haría el trabajo https://stackoverflow.com/a/19087371/8933039

Comment: Te he añadido una respuesta con un par de opciones. Creo que la segunda se adapta mejor a lo que necesitas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para empezar, en lugar de usar `TimeSpan.TryParseExact` tendrás que usar `DateTime.TryParseExact`, dado que `TimeSpan` no tiene entre los formatos admitidos `tt`.

Puedes crear un método similar a este:

```
private static void CompruebaHora(string horaEntrada)
{
    CultureInfo culture = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
    DateTime hora;
    
    if (DateTime.TryParseExact(horaEntrada,"hh:mm tt", culture,DateTimeStyles.None, out hora))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("El formato es hh:mm tt: " + hora.ToString("HH:mm"));
    }
    else if (DateTime.TryParseExact(horaEntrada,"HH:mm", culture,DateTimeStyles.None, out hora))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("El formato es HH:mm: " + hora.ToString("HH:mm"));
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hora no valida");
    }
}
```

Lo probamos asi:

```
string hora1="01:00 PM";
string hora2="13:00";
    
CompruebaHora(hora1);
CompruebaHora(hora2);
```

y nos da la siguiente salida:

> El formato es hh:mm tt: 13:00
>
> El formato es HH:mm: 13:00

---

Otra opción mas sencilla si no te interesa discriminar cual era el formato de entrada, es simplemente pasarle a `DateTime.TryParseExact` todos los formatos que consideras validos, algo asi:

```
private static void CompruebaHora2(string horaEntrada)
{
    CultureInfo culture = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
    DateTime hora;
    
    var formatosValidos = new string[] {"hh:mm tt", "HH:mm"};
    
    if (DateTime.TryParseExact(horaEntrada,formatosValidos, culture,DateTimeStyles.None, out hora))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("El formato es valido: " + hora.ToString("HH:mm"));
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("El formato no es valido");
    }
}
```

Lo probamos:

```
string hora1="01:00 PM";
string hora2="13:00";
string hora3="13:00 PM";
    
CompruebaHora2(hora1);
CompruebaHora2(hora2);
CompruebaHora2(hora3);
```

Y nos da la siguiente salida:

> El formato es valido: 13:00

> El formato es valido: 13:00

> El formato no es valido

Comment: Al parecer me causará problema con la configuración regional del sistema, cuando ingreso `01:00 PM` o `01:00 P.M.` o `12:00 a.m.`  o `12:00 am` en todos los casos la salida dice "El formato no es valido" No me está reconociendo el AM ni PM, incluso especificando una cultura especifica.

Comment: @J.Rodríguez hmm, que raro. [Aqui](https://dotnetfiddle.net/aW8GRQ) puedes ver que funciona. No sera que la entrada lleva algo diferente? (espacios en blanco, etc etc...) Prueba a poner la cadena de entrada directamente en lugar de leerla del campo de texto

Comment: Si utilizo la cultura "en-US", me funciona `01:00 am` o `01:00 pm`, pero si se coloca `a.m.` o `p.m.` no lo reconoce, tampoco funcionan si utilizo esta cúltura: "es-DO" no lo reconoce.

Comment: @J.Rodríguez cierto, es curioso. Pero la solucion es usar `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;`.

Comment: @J.Rodríguez en cuanto a usar `a.m.`. en principio no te va a funcionar. No es una entrada standard. Podrías filtrarlo antes buscando `a.m.` y `p.m.` y reemplazandolo por `am` y `pm`, o crear un FormatInfo y configurar por ejemplo `AMDesignator="a.m."`..pero me parece un poco rebuscado.

Comment: Efectivamente usar InvariantCulture, lo resuelve. En cuanto al a.m. y p.m. Haré un reemplazo, para no complicarme tanto. Gracias